# Looking for a good book on Differential Equations

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, mathematics, differential-equations

I know many of you are tired of book recommendation posts and questions. But I am self learning Theoretical Physics, and I am having a hard time choosing a book to learn differential equations (ODEs). I really want a good understanding of differential equations; I have been told that ODEs and PDEs are the language of physics.

Anyways, if you could be so kind to give me some good recommendations, I would truly appreciate it. I thank you if you read my question and hope you have a wonderful rest of the day.

PD: I new to this site, so this is essentially my first post. I was checking the h bar chatroom. I hope to one day gain the knowledge that you guys have. Truly mesmerizing community. I hope to grow in this environment.

Comment: By Tennebaum from Dover seems good. I have yet to sit down and really go through my copy though. It's really cheap so it's still worth getting along with something else. It has little lessons and you walk through it one-by-one so it might be more digestible than others.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome here!

If you are just starting you may want to use a very didactic textbook:

Zill. - Differential Equations with Boundary Value Problems (look for the solution's manual, it helps if you are an autodidact)

Then a very good one to get into the maths of physics I'd recommend this one:

Arfken - Mathematical Methods for Physicists: A Comprehensive Guide

You may download them from Library Genesis (a bit illegal)